# "OnSessionExpired" equivalent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

Coming from a .NET background, I've been digging for the equivalent of an `OnSessionExpired` or similar event. I'm expecting this event to exist either in addition to an event when the user manually logs out, or for this event to be run both when the session expires on the server-side *and* when the user manually logs out. Does not matter which.

Is there an event that we can hook into when a user's session expires in Laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has own [auth events](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Events). You can listen to those. See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events) for more details.

Also  these events give you  the payload which you can use. For example logout event does provide you payload regarding the user who logged out and the guard it logged out from.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, you can listen for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` event when a user logs out as Mihir mentioned.

As for detecting when a session expires, there's nothing built-in for that since Laravel supports many different sessions drivers and some of them like Memcached and Redis are self-expiring. For drivers that don't self-expire (like the file driver) there's a `gc()` method on the driver for garbage collecting the expired session files, but no events are emitted.

If you want events for session expiry, then you'll have to build that system yourself. I recommend creating web middleware to track the active users, and a scheduled job/command to loop through and prune the expired ones, firing an event for each it found.

Comment: So there's no way to create an event that would fire similar to the `Logout` function, just when the session expires? I'm already tracking the active sessions. It's just that the cleanest and most elegant way I can think of to orchestrate this would be to fire an event on session expire.

Comment: So if there's any way to create and trigger an event on session expiry, please assist me in pursuing that course of action.

Comment: As I said in my answer, there's nothing in the framework that will tell you when a session becomes expired and is removed, but you *can* code your own cron task to do it.

Comment: Ok, going the cron job / scheduling route - I know that Laravel has [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling) but I'm very new to it. Say I have a `sessions` table that I want to loop through once every minute to validate everything is kosher in a **production** environment. How would I go about this? Is it taboo to schedule `php artisan` commands in production? Or should I be writing a `Closure call` which wouldn't be a `php artisan` command? Thanks

Comment: That's a very broad question, requiring a lengthy. I would recommend reading the document you linked a few times as well as any guides you can find, and asking a new question if you run into any specific problems. But no, scheduled commands are not taboo - that's why there are multiple pages documenting how to create them.